# different version of html page downloaded from a same URL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, html

I recently wrote a c# program which scrapes information from ebay. But when i recently test the program i found a wierd thing. 
   i use the code:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Stream data = client.OpenRead(URL);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    this.richTextBox1.Text = s;
    data.Close();
    reader.Close();
```

to download the webpage, and the webpage downloaded from this code is in different version from what is downloaded from a third party download software like flashget , and it is missing some information compare to the other one as well. Can anybody explain this?

**html downloaded from C#**

DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd
   ....

**html downloaded from FlashGet**

DOCTYPE html
   .....

Comment: Just be aware that 'they' might check your HTTP headers, e.g. UserAgent... keep in mind that you're not using an official API!

Comment: I think @home is right. Try "faking" internet explorer with `client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");` (see [full example on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh(v=vs.110)))

Comment: Also, be aware of the legal implications of web scraping, [especially with eBay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBay_v._Bidder%27s_Edge)

Comment: thank you guys. I solved the problem by using FlashGet's API to automate the webpage download. Should also try @PaoloFalabella 's method